# Jquery to check element after filtering

Tags: jquery, html, filter, selector

I am new to Jquery, Even after searching doc and here(stackoverflow), could not find a way to solve it.

Here is my table below, which has 3 rows, each row has a checkbox (first element in a row).

Now the row which has `filtermatch="false" style="display: none;",` will be hidden.

I also has a button to check all and uncheck all. it work if hidden is not applied, but if some element is hidden, check button will also have hidden object checked/unchecked.

My problem is how to get first 2 row checked without modifying any code of the table html (actually, the table is automatically generated by other people's script, I just can write my script to control the display.)

**HTML**

```
<table id="RankTable" border="0" width="800">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th filter="false"><input type="button" id="selectall" value="all"></th>
    <th filter="false">rank</th>
    <th filter-type="ddl">degree</th>
    <th filter-type="ddl">lastposition</th>
    <th filter-type="ddl">workingyear</th>
    <th>realname</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>mobile</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="answer-row" style="">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answers" value="140"> </td>
    <td>2 </td>
    <td>bachelor </td>
    <td>项目经理 </td>
    <td>9 </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><a href="mailto:test06@witz.cn?subject=Invitation for an interview">test06@witz.cn</a></td>
    <td>12316459749816 </td>
</tr>
<tr id="answer-row" style="">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answers" value="139"> </td>
    <td>6 </td>
    <td>bachelor </td>
    <td>项目主管 </td>
    <td>9 </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><a href="mailto:test03@witz.cn?subject=Invitation for an interview">test03@witz.cn</a></td>
    <td>12345646 </td>
</tr>
<tr id="answer-row" filtermatch="false" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answers" value="141"> </td>
    <td>7 </td>
    <td>master </td>
    <td>程序员 </td>
    <td>1 </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td><a href="mailto:test09@witz.cn?subject=Invitation for an interview">test09@witz.cn</a></td>
    <td>56456161 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**js script:**

```
    $('#selectall').toggle(function () {
        $("input[name='answers']").attr("checked", 'true');
        $("input[id='selectall']").attr("value", '{% trans "None" %}');
    }, function () {
        $("input[name='answers']").removeAttr("checked");
        $("input[id='selectall']").attr("value", '{% trans "All" %}');
    });
```

thanks in advance for any inputs.

Comment: thanks everybody, I just figure a solution by myself. Here is the code:
       
        $('#selectall').toggle(function () {
            $('tr[style=""]').find("input[name='answers']").attr("checked", 'true');
            $("input[id='selectall']").attr("value", '{% trans "None" %}');
        }, function () {
            $('tr[style=""]').find("input[name='answers']").removeAttr("checked");
            $("input[id='selectall']").attr("value", '{% trans "All" %}');
        });

Answer (score 0):

use a common class for those row `<tr>` who are visible and add event on it. with this your hidden `<tr>` will not have a 'checked' - checkbox.

html

```
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="answers"  class="answers" value="139"/> </td>
```

js:

```
    $(".answers").attr("checked", 'true');
```

Also when `show()` or `display()` that hidden row you can add back this same class to that row
then checkbox can be check as well.

I have modified your code a bit : **[here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YUVxH/1/)**

Comment: thanks you. jsfiddle is pretty cool tool. But my problem is how to get first 2 row checked without modifying any code of the table code (actually, the table is automatically generated by other people's script, I just can change the script part.)

Comment: is there only 2 two row need be check? OR is there any chances that might add any new row?

Comment: the table is dynamically generated, depending on the backend data, it is possible to have many rows instead of only having 3 row as listed here. since the difference is only in <tr> attributes (filtermatch="false" style="display: none;"), is it possible to check the row whose <tr> does not have these attributes?

Comment: then can you add condition to check for display:'none' like this $('tr').css('display') != 'none'?

Comment: if you found solution please post it as answer :)